# How to sum values of points inside polygons?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a polygon layer of territory and point layer with values from measurements.
I must to add sum values from points layer to polygon layer .
How to do this in PostGIS?

Supplemented:

Point layer is:

```
id|name   |value
1 |first  |547051
2 |second |539949
3 |third  |539864
4 |fourth |539724
5 |fifth  |500208
```

Pattern layer:

[image: pattern layer]

and result must be

```
id|name|sum
55|I5  |1619037
61|H7  |1047259
```

Comment: so you have something like

`point_id|location|value`
`1|<A>|42`
`2|<A>|23`
`3|<B>|99`? 

If location <A> lies inside the polygon <P1> you want a `sum` field of polygon <P1> to read 65 (42+23)?

Answer (score 11):

**Edit**:
field names corresponding to the questions field name

```
SELECT
polygons.id
, polygons.name
, coalesce(sum(points.value),0) AS sum
FROM polygons  
    LEFT JOIN points 
    ON ST_Intersects(polygons.geom, points.geom) 
GROUP BY polygons.id;
```

Then you will get also the polygons without points represented with 0 as sum_value

HTH

Nicklas

Comment: +1 for the [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

Comment: A cast will be needed since coalesce outputs text I realize. A link to the postgresql coalesce function .http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html